# How to initialize a vector with -2147483648 in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I found the problem when initializing a vector with value -2147483648

```
vector<int> vec1({-2147483648});       // invalid, error C2440
vector<int> vec2({0, -2147483648});    // invalid, error C2398
int a = -2147483648;
vector<int> vec3({t});                 // valid
vector<int> vec4({0, t});              // valid
vector<int> vec5(1, -2147483648);      // valid
```

The problem appears when I use VS2013. Does anyone know why?

Comment: -2147483648 is the evil number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-2147483648` is a unary negation operator applied to an integral literal `2147483648`. The latter does not fit into an `int` (assuming it's 32-bit), which means that `-2147483648` is actually an expression of `unsigned` type.

Now, `unsigned` can be implicitly converted to `int` (when the value is unrepresentable, the result is technically implementation-defined, but usually unsurprising). However, this is a narrowing conversion, which is prohibited when used with brace initialization.

Instead of attempting to write the value as a literal, just use `INT_MIN` from the `<limits.h>` header, or `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` from the `<limits>` header, assuming that your intention is to express the minimum value of an `int`.